# recursive CTE or ROW_NUMBER over partition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

Hi below is a small sample, I am trying to find a way to reset a COUNT based on ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND by CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID, The final column is the expected outcome which I cant seem to apply in a query, each time I use ROW_NUMBER over partition I keep getting the wrong results in the it doesn't restart again each time the ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND changes

```
DECLARE @CDO_OP_APPOINTMENT TABLE (CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID int,LOCAL_PATIENT_NUMBER varchar(10),APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME datetime,ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND varchar(10),DESIRED_OUTCOME varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @CDO_OP_APPOINTMENT

VALUES

('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '05/11/2013 10:00', '2',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '12/11/2013 10:00', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '22/11/2013 09:30', '5',    '2'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '03/12/2013 13:00', '3',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '30/12/2013 10:15', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '24/02/2014 09:15', '4',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '24/02/2014 14:15', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '17/03/2014 15:25', '4',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '20/03/2014 18:50', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '23/09/2014 15:55', '5',    '2'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '14/04/2015 16:30', '5',    '3'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '14/04/2015 17:30', '4',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '15/05/2015 14:15', '5',    '1')

SELECT * from @CDO_OP_APPOINTMENT
```

Comment: Specify the expected result. And tag the dbms.

Comment: The last column is my desired outcome, its replicating it in SQL I cant work out

Comment: @Simon, are you using SQL Server? What version?

Comment: @Simon . . . Read what the "partition" tag means.  I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest solution is a difference of row numbers:

```
select a.*,
       row_number() over (partition by CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID, ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND , seqnum - seqnum_2 order by APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME) as desired_result
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID order by APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID, ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND order by APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME) as seqnum_2,
      from @CDO_OP_APPOINTMENT a
     ) a;
```

Comment: Very close to the actual solution this so will also mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve very similar to answer above

```
set dateformat dmy
go

DECLARE @CDO_OP_APPOINTMENT TABLE (CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID int,LOCAL_PATIENT_NUMBER varchar(10),APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME datetime,ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND varchar(10),DESIRED_OUTCOME varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @CDO_OP_APPOINTMENT

VALUES

('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '05/11/2013 10:00', '2',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '12/11/2013 10:00', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '22/11/2013 09:30', '5',    '2'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '03/12/2013 13:00', '3',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '30/12/2013 10:15', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '24/02/2014 09:15', '4',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '24/02/2014 14:15', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '17/03/2014 15:25', '4',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '20/03/2014 18:50', '5',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '23/09/2014 15:55', '5',    '2'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '14/04/2015 16:30', '5',    '3'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '14/04/2015 17:30', '4',    '1'),
('480805568',   'HEY1030785',   '15/05/2015 14:15', '5',    '1')


SELECT CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID ,LOCAL_PATIENT_NUMBER ,APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME ,ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID,Seq1-Seq2,ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND ORDER BY APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME) AS DESIRED_OUTCOME 
FROM
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID ORDER BY APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME) AS Seq1,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CDO_OP_REFERRAL_UNIQUE_ID,ATTENDED_OR_DID_NOT_ATTEND ORDER BY APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME) AS Seq2

 from @CDO_OP_APPOINTMENT
 )t
 ORDER BY APPOINTMENT_START_DATE_TIME
```